# Transferring documents from one account to another

Tags: overleaf

I have been writing up my thesis on my old university account (Overleaf). Recently, I have been informed that they are going to close down my account and thus I will no longer have access to Latex through that individual account.

My plan is to someone copy and paste all my existing work onto a new account. Is there a more efficient way of doing this? Specially as I can't open two different Latex accounts on the same computer at the same time!

Thanks

Comment: It is entirely unclear to me what you are asking. Your LaTeX project are just some files that can be copied to a different drive or computer just like any other file.

Comment: Yh sorry. I am using Overleaf.

Comment: Ah, in that case this is off-topic here. You should contact Overleaf support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you should contact Overleaf support (support@overleaf.com) for anything to do with account management. I work there, and I can tell you what we'll advise you to do if you get in contact with us.

Your Overleaf account is independent of your university, other than the email address used. So, if you will lose access to that email address, you should change the primary registered email address to something permanent. Go to Account > Settings, then click "Add email" and enter a current valid email address. A confirmation email will be sent to you, and once you confirm ownership of that email address by clicking the link in the email, you will have the option to make that email address the default. Then, you can delete your old university email address.

Comment: Thank you so much.